# java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default:

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

when I use robolectric to make UT, the BaseTest is defined as that:

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

```
testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') {
}
testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5") {

}
testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0") {

}
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0') {

}


@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 18)
public class TestBase {
    @Test
    public void testBase() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

but there may show these error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.robolectric.annotation.Config.application()
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:128)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:210)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:40)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

And I find some way to solve, I change it :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", application = android.app.Application.class)
public class TestBase {

    @Test
    public void testBase() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

this way don't solve this problom

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have you tried googling the problem? Please look at the help on how to ask and what to do before. I found at least one comment at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1620 that seems relevant.

Comment: Also, your question isn't clear. Did you find a way to solve it or not?